# What's the difference between Project Folder and Source Folder in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

For me, both things are exactly the same. What's the point of these? Where's the difference between Project Folder and Source Folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Project Folder** is where the *nbproject* folder (Netbeans configuration for the project) is stored. The **Source Folder** is where your have all your stuff.

They can be different but you need to check the *Put NetBeans metadata into a separate directory* in the New Project wizard. Afterwards, it can't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The Project Folder will have have the build and dist folders in it along with the source folder. The source folder only contains your source code where the project folder hold the compiled classes, meta information, test cases, and distribution folder.